# How to figure out in which file and code line a cypress test has failed?

Tags: cypress

When a cypress test fails, how do I get the file and code line where it failed. In particular, if I have a long test (as suggested in the [best practices](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Creating-%E2%80%9Ctiny%E2%80%9D-tests-with-a-single-assertion) document), the `it` is not enough to locate the failed test.

Comment: I'm curious to see a solution for this. The current solution we use is to cut up the testscript in many small ```it```s. Every it is unique qua text, so we can pretty clear determine were the fail is.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [**hack to get some stack traces**](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/881#issuecomment-342308529) (does not always work).

There are plans in the [cypress](https://github.com/cypress-io/) project to add official support for tracking the source location of a failed test:

- Improve Test Runner error experience [cypress/issues/3762](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3762)
- Obtain spec file source lines when a command fails  [cypress/issues/3966](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3966)

Answer (score 0):

One option which I am following is the `debugger` option which is added before the line to see where the test is failing. In the below test I am receiving an `heightInput` from a function called `transportMe()`and passing that value into that text field. So in the below case the test throws with an error 'transt' is not defined. So  I have added a `debugger` before the starting of `for loop` and press F12 while running, then it will navigate to the line in console and we can further F11 to see where it fails.( *This is working chrome browser, i haven't tried in Electron* ). Not very sure if this helps and this is what you are looking for !

```
describe('Using the debugger option in Cypress', () => {
  it('Check the debugger is working here', ()=> {
    cy.visit('some_url_here');    
    const getsomeInput = transportMe();
    cy.get('input[name="heightInput"]').type(getsomeInput );

    })
})

function transportMe(){
  var trans = 150;
  debugger;
  for(var i=0; i<=transt; i++)
   {
     trans = trans + 1;
     return trans;
   }
}
```

[image]